# Why does this golang program create a memory leak?

Tags: go, memory-leaks, concurrency

I am trying to understand concurrency and goroutines, and had a couple questions about the following experimental code:

1. Why does it create a memory leak? I thought that a return at the end of the goroutine would allow memory associated with it to get cleaned up.
2. Why do my loops almost never reach 999? In fact, when I output to a file and study the output, I notice that it rarely prints integers in double digits; the first time it prints "99" is line 2461, and for "999" line 6120. This behavior is unexpected to me, which clearly means I don't really understand what is going on with goroutine scheduling.

Disclaimer:

**Be careful running the code below, it can crash your system if you don't stop it after a few seconds!**

CODE

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for {
      // spawn four worker goroutines
      spawnWorkers(4, wg)
      // wait for the workers to finish
      wg.Wait()
    }
}

func spawnWorkers(max int, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
  for n := 0; n < max; n++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            f(n)
          return
        }()
    }   
}

func f(n int) {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
      fmt.Println(n, ":", i)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're copying the `sync.WaitGroup`; pass a pointer to it instead.

Comment: running `go vet` will show you the error.

Comment: Hi @TimCooper, in regards to the memory leak, you are correct! That does indeed fix issue #1, BUT in that scenario goroutine 4 runs far more than the others; when outputting to a .txt file, I can see that the first time #1 runs is line 1640001. That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @dpog your output for `n` isn't what you're expecting it to be. See: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Tim Cooper, JimB, and Greg for their helpful comments. The corrected version of the code is posted below for reference.

The two fixes were to pass in the **WaitGroup** by reference, which fixed the memory leak, and to pass **n** correctly into the anonymous goroutine, and

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for {
      // spawn four worker goroutines
      spawnWorkers(4,&wg)
      // wait for the workers to finish
      wg.Wait()
    }
}

func spawnWorkers(max int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
  for n := 0; n < max; n++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(n int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            f(n)
          return
        }(n)
    }   
}

func f(n int) {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
      fmt.Println(n, ":", i)
    }
}
```